# Как анимировать колеса картинки автомобиля в формате png, движущегося и останавливающегося с помощью CSS?

Tags: css, html5, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Я пытаюсь анимировать автомобиль с помощью CSS. Мне удалось анимировать колеса и машину.
Машина движется и останавливается, а затем уезжает. Эта анимация зацикливается.

Теперь мне нужно остановить колеса, когда машина остановится. Но я не могу этого достичь.

Ниже код, что у меня получилось:

```css
@keyframes wheel{
 0%{
   transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  
    35% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg)
  }
  36%,
  56% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg)
  }
  
 100%{
   transform: rotate(-359deg)
  }
}

@keyframes moving {
  0% {
    right: -80em;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  35% {
    right: 0;
  }
  36%,
  56% {
    right: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  100% {
    right: 120%;
  }
}

@keyframes stableWheel {
  from {transform: translateY(-.0em);}
  to {transform: translateY(-.0em);}
}


.car{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height:271px;
  overflow:hidden;
    animation: moving 10s linear -2s infinite;
}
.carbody{
  animation: carmove 3.1s infinite linear;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWNOG.png') 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 271px;
  position: relative; 
  width: 600px;
  z-index: 125;
}



.weel{

  animation: wheel 0.7s infinite linear;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Osjx.png') 0 0;
  height: 85px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 67%;
  width: 85px;
  z-index: 200;
}
.weel1{left: 85px;}
.weel2{left: 454px;}

/*animations*/
@keyframes carmove{
  0%{transform: translateY(0px);}
  25%{transform: translateY(1px)}
  29%{transform: translateY(2px)}
  33%{transform: translateY(3px)}
  47%{transform: translateY(0px)}
  58%{transform: translateY(1px)}
  62%{transform: translateY(2px)}
  66%{transform: translateY(3px)}
  75%{transform: translateY(1px)}
  100%{transform: translateY(0px)}
}




body {
  -webkit-animation: color-fade 10s infinite;
  -moz-animation: color-fade 10s infinite;
  animation: color-fade 10s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color-fade {
  0% { background: #9a5342; }
  25% { background: #fffc0c; }
  50% { background: #e46d00; }
  75% { background: #ff3506; }
  100% { background: #9a5342; }
}


.stopedWeel{
     animation: stableWheel .2s linear infinite alternate;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
  <div class="carbody"></div>
  <div class="weel weel1"></div>
  <div class="weel weel2"></div>
</div>
```

Анимация колёс:

```
@keyframes wheel{
     0%{
       transform: rotate(0deg)
      }

        35% {
        transform: rotate(-90deg)
      }
      36%,
      56% {
        transform: rotate(-180deg)
      }

     100%{
       transform: rotate(-359deg)
      }
    }
```

Если вы запустите мой код, все колеса будут нервно  подрагивать.
Может кто-нибудь, дать совет, как это устранить?

Comment: премного благодарен

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Да всё ждал, ждал, что сделаешь лучше и забыл в конце-концов :) Наткнулся случайно сегодня, что вопрос не принят

Comment: не знаю как еще это улучшить:)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Да и так нормально, просто я объяснил, почему затянул с решением

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это конечно не имеет отношения к css

Чтобы посчитать на сколько повернуть колесо - необходимо пройденный путь разделить на Math.PI и умножить на радиус колеса:

```js
let x, tx = 600;
svg.setAttribute('width', innerWidth - 20)
addEventListener('mousedown', e => x =  tx - e.x);
addEventListener('mouseup', e => x = null);
addEventListener('mousemove', e => x && relocate(tx = e.x + x));

function relocate(tx){
  car.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${tx},0)`)
  wheel1.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${tx/Math.PI*8})`)
  wheel2.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${tx/Math.PI*8})`)
}

requestAnimationFrame(drive);

function drive(t){
  relocate(tx = 100 + easeIn((2000-t)/2000)*500)
  t<2000 && requestAnimationFrame(drive);
}

function easeIn(t) { 
  return t*t*t 
}
```

```html
drag a car

<svg id=svg>

  <defs>
    <g id=wheel>
      <circle  r=8></circle>
      <circle stroke-dasharray=1,1 r=3 stroke-width=6></circle>
    </g>
  </defs>
  
  <path d="m0,58h1000" stroke=black></path>
  
  <g fill=#eee stroke=black id=car>
    <path d="m10,50 h5 a10,10,0,0,1,20,0 h55 a10,10,0,0,1,20,0
      h5 l2,-18 l-3,3 l-25,-2 a25,10,0,0,0,-50,0 l-30,2 l-3,3 z"></path>
      <g transform=translate(25,50)>
        <use id=wheel1 xlink:href="#wheel"></use>
      </g>
      <g transform=translate(100,50)>
        <use id=wheel2 xlink:href="#wheel"></use>
      </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7):

### Анимация CSS

Чтобы сделать это проще, используйте одинаковую продолжительность для обеих анимаций, затем увеличьте угол поворота для управления колесом. Просто убедитесь, что вы вернетесь к `n * 360deg` в конце (не обязательно в этом случае, поскольку в движении автомобиля нет цикла)

Я также оптимизировал ваш код для использования процентного значения, чтобы вы могли легко контролировать всю машину, просто регулируя ширину основного элемента:

```css
.car{
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  animation: moving 10s linear -2s infinite;
}
.car:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  animation: carmove 3.1s infinite linear;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWNOG.png') center/cover;
  padding-top:45.25%;
}

.weel{
  animation: wheel 10s infinite -2s linear;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Osjx.png') center/cover;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0.8%;
  width: 14.15%;
}
.weel:before {
   content:"";
   display:block;
   padding-top:100%;
}
.weel1{left: 14.5%;}
.weel2{right: 10%;}

/*animations*/
@keyframes carmove{
  0%{transform: translateY(0px);}
  25%{transform: translateY(1px)}
  29%{transform: translateY(2px)}
  33%{transform: translateY(3px)}
  47%{transform: translateY(0px)}
  58%{transform: translateY(1px)}
  62%{transform: translateY(2px)}
  66%{transform: translateY(3px)}
  75%{transform: translateY(1px)}
  100%{transform: translateY(0px)}
}

@keyframes wheel{
 0%{
   transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  35% {
    transform: rotate(-920deg)
  }
  36%,
  56% {
    transform: rotate(-920deg)
  }
 100%{
   transform: rotate(-1440deg)
  }
}

@keyframes moving {
  0% {
    right: -80em;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  35% {
    right: 0;
  }
  36%,
  56% {
    right: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  100% {
    right: 120%;
  }
}

body {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
  <div class="weel weel1"></div>
  <div class="weel weel2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

### Анимация SVG

*Сценарий*

1. Автомобиль появляется справа.
   Колеса вращаются
2. Остановка автомобиля на середине пути.
   Колеса не вращаются
3. Автомобиль снова едет.
   Колеса вращаются
4. Повторение всего цикла.

Зачем я написал этот простой алгоритм?
Только для того, чтобы чётко следовать ему в порядке запуска параллельных и последовательных анимаций.

В отличии от анимаций CSS в SVG можно обойтись без кропотливых расчётов тайминга.

И как написано в сценарии, так и реализовывать запуск, остановку анимаций

Например:

- пауза следует после окончания движения на первом участке пути:

`begin="an_move1.end"`

- Движение на втором участке пути начнется после окончания паузы

`begin="an_pause.end"`

*Более подробные объяснения смотрите в комментариях к коду*

```css
body {
  -webkit-animation: color-fade 10s infinite;
  -moz-animation: color-fade 10s infinite;
  animation: color-fade 10s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color-fade {
  0% { background: #9a5342; }
  25% { background: #fffc0c; }
  50% { background: #e46d00; }
  75% { background: #ff3506; }
  100% { background: #9a5342; }
}

.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1200" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
  <!-- Car -->
<g id="car" transform="translate(-2400,0)">
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWNOG.png" width="100%" height="100%" />

 <g id="wheel_left" transform=" translate(85,430) scale(0.145)" >
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Osjx.png" width="100%" height="100%" >
     <!-- Анимация вращения левого колеса -->
 <animateTransform
     id="an_left"
     attributeName="transform"
     type="rotate"
     begin="0s;6s;16s;26s;36s;46s;56s"
     end="an_pause.begin"
     values="
     0 300 400;
    -360 300 400"
     dur="1s"
     repeatCount="indefinite"
 />
 </image>
 </g>  
     
 <g id="wheel_right" transform=" translate(455,430) scale(0.145)" >
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Osjx.png" width="100%" height="100%" > 
     <!-- Анимация вращения правого колеса -->
    <animateTransform
      id="an_right"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      begin="0s;6s;16s;26s;36s;46s;56s"
      end="an_pause.begin"
      values="
      0 300 400;
    -360 300 400"
      dur="1s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    />
 </image>
 </g>
</g>   
<!-- Анимация движения автомобиля до остановки -->
 <animateTransform
   id="an_move1"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="0s;an_move2.end"
   values="2400;800"
   dur="4s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 />  
 <!-- Пауза движения автомобиля  -->
 <animateTransform
   id="an_pause"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="an_move1.end"
   values="800"
   dur="2s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 /> 
 <!-- Анимация движения автомобиля после остановки -->
  <animateTransform
   id="an_move2"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="an_pause.end"
   values="800;-600"
   dur="4s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 /> 

</svg>   
</div>
```