# Неравномерная анимация движения объекта со спецэффектами

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, css-animation

Вопрос инспирирован ответом  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1048677/28748

Как сделать неравномерную анимацию движения автомобиля?

То есть должно быть ускорение, замедление, остановка, трогание с места. 
Необходимо, чтобы при торможении загорались стоп сигналы. При остановке мигали сигнальные фонари поворота.

Получилось сделать мигание сигнальных фонарей поворота при движении автомобиля.

```css
body {
  -webkit-animation: color-fade 10s infinite;
  -moz-animation: color-fade 10s infinite;
  animation: color-fade 10s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color-fade {
  0% { background: #9a5342; }
  25% { background: #fffc0c; }
  50% { background: #e46d00; }
  75% { background: #ff3506; }
  100% { background: #9a5342; }
}

.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
#turn{
 fill:gold;
 stroke:none;
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1200" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
  <!-- Car -->
<g id="car" transform="translate(-2400,0)">
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWNOG.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
   <!-- Сигнальные фонари -->
   <g transform="translate(-30,265)">
   <path id="turn" opacity="0" d="m78.3 155.8c8.3-7.5 19-8.8 26.7-10 7-1.1-1.7 11.5-11.1 18.2-4.8 3.4-20-4.3-15.7-8.3zM543.2 115.6"  >
   <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="0s" dur="2s" values="0;1;0;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
   </path>
 </g>  
 <g id="wheel_left" transform=" translate(85,430) scale(0.145)" >
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Osjx.png" width="100%" height="100%" >
     <!-- Анимация вращения левого колеса -->
 <animateTransform
     id="an_left"
  attributeName="transform"
  type="rotate"
  begin="0s;6s;16s;26s;36s;46s;56s"
  end="an_pause.begin"
  values="
  0 300 400;
 -360 300 400"
  dur="1s"
  repeatCount="indefinite"
 />
 </image>
 </g>  
     
 <g id="wheel_right" transform=" translate(455,430) scale(0.145)" >
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Osjx.png" width="100%" height="100%" > 
     <!-- Анимация вращения правого колеса -->
    <animateTransform
   id="an_right"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="rotate"
   begin="0s;6s;16s;26s;36s;46s;56s"
   end="an_pause.begin"
   values="
   0 300 400;
 -360 300 400"
   dur="1s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
 />
 </image>
 </g>
</g>   
<!-- Анимация движения автомобиля до остановки -->
 <animateTransform
   id="an_move1"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="0s;an_move2.end"
   values="2400;800"
   dur="4s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 />  
 <!-- Пауза движения автомобиля  -->
 <animateTransform
   id="an_pause"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="an_move1.end"
   values="800"
   dur="2s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 /> 
 <!-- Анимация движения автомобиля после остановки -->
  <animateTransform
   id="an_move2"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="an_pause.end"
   values="800;-600"
   dur="4s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 /> 

</svg>  
</div>
```

- Как согласовать их моргание со временем остановки и стоянки
  автомобиля?
- Как согласовать включение стоп сигнала при тормажении?
- Как реализовать уменьшение, увеличение скорости движения автомобиля
  при торможении и трогании с места?

Answer (score 7):

Сначала код решения, если анимация понравилась и стало интересно, как это сделано:

Читайте ниже, но ..**Tl;dr**   `многа букоф`

### Смотрите комментарии в коде программы и раскройте окно на полный просмотр

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
overflow:visible;
margin:-0.3em;
background: rgb(119,124,116);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(119,124,116,1) 0%, rgba(83,159,53,0.938813025210084) 100%);
}
#turn{
fill:gold;
stroke:none;
}

#stopLamp {
fill:crimson;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1400" height="600" viewBox="0 -140 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >   
  
 <g transform="translate(0,-190) scale(1.4 1)">
 
 <!-- Фон города -->
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekgpJ.png" width="1383" height="637" />
   </g>
   <!-- Дорога с разметкой    -->
    
   <g transform="skewX(45) translate(-700 103) ">   
   <rect x="-10" y="350" width="2400" height="200" fill="grey" stroke="#bababa" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="100 2"/> 
     <path d="M0 450 L2400 450" fill="white" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray=" 100 55 140 35" />
    </g>  
  <!-- Car -->
<g id="car" transform="translate(-2400,0)">
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWNOG.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
   <!-- Сигнальные фонари -->
   <g transform="translate(-30,265)">
   <path id="turn" opacity="0" d="m78.3 155.8c8.3-7.5 19-8.8 26.7-10 7-1.1-1.7 11.5-11.1 18.2-4.8 3.4-20-4.3-15.7-8.3zM543.2 115.6"  >
   <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="an_move1.end" dur="1s" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="3"/>
   </path>
   <!-- Стоп сигнал -->
   <path id="stopLamp" opacity="0" d="m543.2 115.6c3.3-1.5 24-5.4 35.3-2 4.1 1.2 8.3 3.9 10.2 7.7 2.5 4.8 1 11.2  0.6 16.2-0.8 8.7 8.6 15.2 3.7 14.5-7.8-1.1-19.7-7.5-28.2-13.7-8.4-6.2-25.4-21.1-21.6-22.8z" >
   <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="an_move1.end-1.5s;an_pause.end+1.5s" dur="1.2s" values="0;1" repeatCount="1"/>
   </path> 
 </g>  
 <g id="wheel_left" transform=" translate(85,430) scale(0.145)" >
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Osjx.png" width="100%" height="100%" >
     <!-- Анимация вращения правого колеса -->
 <animateTransform
     id="an_left"
  attributeName="transform"
  type="rotate"
  begin="0s;6s;16s;26s;36s;46s;56s;66s;76s"
  end="an_pause.begin"
  values="
 0 300 400;
  -360 300 400"
  dur="1s"
  repeatCount="indefinite"
 />
 </image>
 </g>  
    
 <g id="wheel_right" transform=" translate(455,430) scale(0.145)" >
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Osjx.png" width="100%" height="100%" > 
     <!-- Анимация вращения левого колеса -->
    <animateTransform
   id="an_right"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="rotate"
   begin="0s;6s;16s;26s;36s;46s;56s;66s;76s"
   end="an_pause.begin"
   values="
   0 300 400;
  -360 300 400"
   dur="1s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
 />
 </image>
 </g>
</g>   
<!-- Анимация движения автомобиля до остановки -->
 <animateTransform
   id="an_move1"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="0s;an_move2.end"
   values="2400;1800;1350;1200;900;800" 
   keyTimes="0;0.2;0.4;0.5;0.7;1" 
   dur="4s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 />  
 <!-- Пауза движения автомобиля  -->
 <animateTransform
   id="an_pause"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="an_move1.end"
   values="800"
   dur="2s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 /> 
 <!-- Анимация движения автомобиля после остановки -->
  <animateTransform
   id="an_move2"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="an_pause.end"
   values="800;750;100;0;-600"
   keyTimes="0;0.2;0.5;0.9;1"
   dur="4s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 />  

</svg>
<div class="container"> 
</div>
```

**Анимация сигнальных фонарей**

Найти место и задать границы сигнальных фонарей можно методом `тыка` с помощью `translate()` элемента SVG. Но быстрее, точнее будет это сделать с помощью векторного редактора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Наносим узловые точки по контуру сигнального фонаря с помощью инструмента `Рисовать кривые Безье`
2. Сделать узловые точки автоматически сглаженными
3. Рычагами управления узловых точек добиваемся нужной формы кривой.
4. Копируем `path`
5. Создаем анимацию для этого `Path`

```
<!-- Сигнальные фонари -->
   <g transform="translate(-30,265)">
     <path id="turn" opacity="0" d="m78.3 155.8c8.3-7.5 19-8.8 26.7-10 7-1.1-1.7 11.5-11.1
         18.2-4.8 3.4-20-4.3-15.7-8.3zM543.2 115.6"  >
      <animate
        attributeName="opacity"
        begin="0s"
        dur="2s"
        values="0;1;0;1;0"
        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
     </path>
    </g>
```

- Точно также создаем `path` и анимацию для задних фонарей
  стоп-сигнала.

Как сделать привязку включения, выключения анимации сигнальных фонарей к этапам торможения и разгона будет показано ниже.

**Управление неравномерными анимациями торможения, разгона**

Неравномерность движения задаётся парой атрибутов:

```
values="2400;1800;1350;1200;1030;800"  массив отрезков пути
keyTimes="0;0.2;0.4;0.5;0.6;1"   массив отрезков времени
```

каждому отрезку пути соответствует своё время его прохождения.  Понятно, что чем больше время прохождения отрезка, тем меньше будет скорость. 
Последний короткий этап `1030;800` будет пройден за `1 - 0.6 = 0.4 * 100 = 40%` от общего времени - `100%`. Это торможение.

```
<!-- Анимация движения автомобиля до остановки -->
 <animateTransform
   id="an_move1"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="0s;an_move2.end"
   values="2400;1800;1350;1200;1030;800" 
   keyTimes="0;0.2;0.4;0.5;0.6;1" 
   dur="4s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 />
```

Другие значения параметров в паре `values`, `keyTimes` реализуют иллюзию трогания с места и разгон автомобиля

```
<!-- Анимация движения автомобиля после остановки -->
  <animateTransform
   id="an_move2"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="an_pause.end"
   values="800;750;100;0;-600"
   keyTimes="0;0.2;0.5;0.9;1"
   dur="4s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 />
```

Понятно, что подбирать значения параметров утомительно и неэффективно.

Для этих целей есть [онлайн генератор keyTimes](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1674)

**Привязка работы сигнальных фонарей к этапам анимации торможения, остановки, разгона автомобиля**

*Весь путь и время анимации разбиты на три диапазона:*

1. Движение до остановки `id="an_move1"` который длится - `4s`

Условие запуска срабатывания стоп-сигнала: `begin="an_move1.end-1.5s`, что означает запуск за `1.5s` до полной остановки автомобиля

2. Остановка, стоянка автомобиля  Должны моргать фонари аварийной остановки

`begin="an_move1.end" dur="1s" values="0;1;0;1;0" repeatCount="3"`

Такая запись обозначает - запуск анимации моргания после полной остановки автомобиля `an_move1.end` в течении 1s, повтор 3 раза.

3. Трогание с места и разгон автомобиля после стоянки

Анимации моргания фонарей уже закончились и только включится в середине пути стоп сигналы при очередном торможении.

**Добавляем дорогу с разметкой и фон города**

```
<!-- Фон города -->
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekgpJ.png" width="1383" height="637" />
   </g>
   <!-- Дорога с разметкой    -->

   <g transform="skewX(45) translate(-700 103) ">     
      <rect x="-10" y="350" width="2400" height="200" fill="grey" stroke="#bababa" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="100 2"/> 
        <path d="M0 450 L2400 450" fill="white" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray=" 100 55 140 35" />
    </g>
```

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
background: rgb(119,124,116);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(119,124,116,1) 0%, rgba(83,159,53,0.938813025210084) 100%);
}
#turn{
fill:gold;
stroke:none;
}

#stopLamp {
fill:crimson;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1400" height="600" viewBox="0 -140 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >   
  
 <g transform="translate(0,-190) scale(1.4 1)">
 
 <!-- Фон города -->
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekgpJ.png" width="1383" height="637" />
   </g>
   <!-- Дорога с разметкой    -->
    
   <g transform="skewX(45) translate(-700 103) ">   
   <rect x="-10" y="350" width="2400" height="200" fill="grey" stroke="#bababa" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="100 2"/> 
     <path d="M0 450 L2400 450" fill="white" stroke="white" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray=" 100 55 140 35" />
    </g>  
  <!-- Car -->
<g id="car" transform="translate(-2400,0)">
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWNOG.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
   <!-- Сигнальные фонари -->
   <g transform="translate(-30,265)">
   <path id="turn" opacity="0" d="m78.3 155.8c8.3-7.5 19-8.8 26.7-10 7-1.1-1.7 11.5-11.1 18.2-4.8 3.4-20-4.3-15.7-8.3zM543.2 115.6"  >
   <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="an_move1.end" dur="1s" values="0;1;0" repeatCount="3"/>
   </path>
   <!-- Стоп сигнал -->
   <path id="stopLamp" opacity="0" d="m543.2 115.6c3.3-1.5 24-5.4 35.3-2 4.1 1.2 8.3 3.9 10.2 7.7 2.5 4.8 1 11.2  0.6 16.2-0.8 8.7 8.6 15.2 3.7 14.5-7.8-1.1-19.7-7.5-28.2-13.7-8.4-6.2-25.4-21.1-21.6-22.8z" >
   <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="an_move1.end-1.5s;an_pause.end+1.5s" dur="1.2s" values="0;1" repeatCount="1"/>
   </path> 
 </g>  
 <g id="wheel_left" transform=" translate(85,430) scale(0.145)" >
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Osjx.png" width="100%" height="100%" >
     <!-- Анимация вращения правого колеса -->
 <animateTransform
     id="an_left"
  attributeName="transform"
  type="rotate"
  begin="0s;6s;16s;26s;36s;46s;56s;66s;76s"
  end="an_pause.begin"
  values="
 0 300 400;
  -360 300 400"
  dur="1s"
  repeatCount="indefinite"
 />
 </image>
 </g>  
    
 <g id="wheel_right" transform=" translate(455,430) scale(0.145)" >
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Osjx.png" width="100%" height="100%" > 
     <!-- Анимация вращения левого колеса -->
    <animateTransform
   id="an_right"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="rotate"
   begin="0s;6s;16s;26s;36s;46s;56s;66s;76s"
   end="an_pause.begin"
   values="
   0 300 400;
  -360 300 400"
   dur="1s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
 />
 </image>
 </g>
</g>   
<!-- Анимация движения автомобиля до остановки -->
 <animateTransform
   id="an_move1"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="0s;an_move2.end"
   values="2400;1800;1350;1200;900;800" 
   keyTimes="0;0.2;0.4;0.5;0.7;1" 
   dur="4s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 />  
 <!-- Пауза движения автомобиля  -->
 <animateTransform
   id="an_pause"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="an_move1.end"
   values="800"
   dur="2s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 /> 
 <!-- Анимация движения автомобиля после остановки -->
  <animateTransform
   id="an_move2"
   xlink:href="#car"
   attributeName="transform"
   type="translate"
   begin="an_pause.end"
   values="800;750;100;0;-600"
   keyTimes="0;0.2;0.5;0.9;1"
   dur="4s"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
 />  
   
</svg>
<div class="container"> 
</div>
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/full/abbrxeW)